# How do I get the LOGFONT structure from a HFONT handle?

Tags: c++, winapi, fonts

If I have the handle of a window, say `hWnd`, I can get the handle to its font type, say `hFont`, like this:

```
HFONT hFont = SendMessage(hWnd, WM_GETFONT, NULL, NULL);
```

After this point, how do I obtain a [`LOGFONT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145037(v=vs.85).aspx) structure (which contains many features of the font), from this [`HFONT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) handle?

My purpose is not to create a font from scratch by calling [`CreateFont()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183499(v=vs.85).aspx). I want to read font properties into a `LOGFONT` structure, then arbitrarily modify it, and finally update the font by calling the [`CreateFontIndirect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183500(v=vs.85).aspx) function and passing the modified `LOGFONT` object to it.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for [`GetObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144904.aspx).

Comment: This is the correct answer for the question asked.  You may also find the LOGFONT fields in a NONCLIENTMETRICS structure (which you can query with SystemParametersInfo) to be useful if you're trying to select fonts that are compatible with the ones the system uses in the UI.